# Sending data back and forth between two Activities in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Activity ActivityA say. From ActivityA I start ActivityB using an Intent, sending some string data to the new activity. ActivityA gets pushed into the background, not destroyed.

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
newActivity.putExtras("SomeString", "important data");
startActivity(newactivity);
```

Now I want to manipulate the string data and send it back to AcitivtyA. Not a new instance of ActivityA, but the instance that has been paused. I am unsure how to do this. ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start B with [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and override [onActvityResult()](http://onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20Intent%29) in A. Before you finish B you will need to call [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20Intent%29) to set the data you want to send back to A.

Read the section of [Starting Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using start activity for result. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)